# Creation and addressing arrays in AVR Assembly (Using the ATMega8535)

Tags: arrays, assembly, avr, atmel

I am having trouble with the creation and addressing of an array created purely in assembly using the instruction set for the Atmel ATMega8535.

What I understand so far is as follows:

- The array contains contiguous data that is equal in length.
- The creation of the array involves defining the beginning and end locations of the array (much like you would the stack).
- You would address an index in the array by adding an offset of the base address of the array.

What I am looking to do specifically is create a 1-D array of 8-bit integers with predefined values populating it during initialization it does not have to be written to, only addressed when needed. The problem ultimately lying in not being able to translate the logic into the assembly code.

I have tried with little progress to do so using support from the following books:

- Some Assembly Required:  Assembly Language Programming with the AVR Microcontroller by Timothy S Margush
- Get Going with...AVR Microcontrollers by Peter Sharpe

Any help, advice or further resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array is read-only, you do not need to copy it to RAM. You can
keep it in Flash and read it from there when needed. This will save you
precious RAM, at the cost of slower access (read from RAM is 2 cycles,
read from flash is 3 cycles).

You can declare your array like this:

```
.global my_array
.type   my_array, @object
my_array:
    .byte 12, 34, 56, 78
```

Then, to read a member of the array, you have to compute:

```
adress of member = array base address + member index
```

If your members were more than one byte, you would have to also multiply
the index by the size, but this is not the case here. Then, you put the
address of the required member in the Z register and issue an `lpm`
instruction. Here is a function implementing this logic:

```
.global read_data
; input:    r24 = array index, r1 = 0
; output:   r24 = array value
; clobbers: r30, r31
read_data:
    ldi r30, lo8(my_array)  ; load Z = address of my_array
    ldi r31, hi8(my_array)  ; ...high byte also
    add r30, r24            ; add the array index
    adc r31, r1             ; ...and add 0 to propagate the carry
    lpm r24, Z
    ret
```

@scottt advised you to first write in C, then look at the generated
assembly. I consider this very good advice, let's follow it:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

__flash const uint8_t my_array[] = {12, 34, 56, 78};

uint8_t read_data(uint8_t index)
{
    return my_array[index];
}
```

The `__flash` keyword identifying a “named address space” is an embedded
C extension [supported by
gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html). The
generated assembly is slightly different from the previous one: instead
of computing `base_address + index`, gcc does `index − (−base_address)`:

```
read_data:
    mov r30, r24                ; load Z = array index
    ldi r31, 0                  ; ...high byte of index is 0
    subi r30, lo8(-(my_array))  ; subtract -(address of my array)
    sbci r31, hi8(-(my_array))  ; ...high byte also
    lpm r24, Z
    ret
```

This is just as efficient as the previous hand-rolled assembly, except
that it does not need the r1 register to be initialized to zero. But
keeping r1 to zero is part of the gcc ABI anyway, so it should make no
difference.

### The role of the linker

This section is meant to answer the question in the comment: how can we
access the array if we do not know its address? The answer is: we access
it by its name, just like in the code snippets above. Choosing the final
address for the array, as well as replacing the name by the appropriate
address, is the linker’s job.

Assembling (with `avr-gcc -c`) and disassembling (with `avr-objdump -d`)
the first code snippet gives this:

```
my_array.o, section .text:
00000000 <my_array>:
   0:   0c 22 38 4e        ."8N
```

If we were compiling from C, gcc would have put the array in the
.progmem.data section instead of .text, but it makes little difference.
The numbers “0c 22 38 4e” are the array contents, in hex. The characters
to the right are the ASCII equivalents, ‘.’ being the placeholder for
non printing characters.

The object file also carries this symbol table, shown by `avr-nm`:

```
my_array.o:
00000000 T my_array
```

meaning the symbol “my_array” has been defined as referring to offset 0
into the .text section (implied by “T”) of this object.

Assembling and disassembling the second code snippet gives this:

```
read_data.o, section .text:
00000000 <read_data>:
   0:   e0 e0        ldi r30, 0x00
   2:   f0 e0        ldi r31, 0x00
   4:   e8 0f        add r30, r24
   6:   f1 1d        adc r31, r1
   8:   84 91        lpm r24, Z
   a:   08 95        ret
```

Comparing the disassembly with the actual source code, it can be seen
that the assembler replaced the address of my_array with 0x00, which is
almost guaranteed to be wrong. But it also left a note to the linker in
the form of “relocation records”, shown by `avr-objdump -r`:

```
read_data.o, RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000000 R_AVR_LO8_LDI     my_array
00000002 R_AVR_HI8_LDI     my_array
```

This tells the linker that the `ldi` instructions at offsets 0x00 and
0x02 are intended to load the low byte and the high byte (respectively)
of the final address of my_array. The object file also carries this
symbol table:

```
read_data.o:
         U my_array
00000000 T read_data
```

where the “U” line means the file makes use of an undefined symbol named
“my_array”.

Linking these pieces together, with a suitable main(), yields a binary
containing the C runtime from avr-lbc, together with our code:

```
0000003c <my_array>:
  3c:   0c 22 38 4e        ."8N

00000040 <read_data>:
  40:   ec e3        ldi r30, 0x3C
  42:   f0 e0        ldi r31, 0x00
  44:   e8 0f        add r30, r24
  46:   f1 1d        adc r31, r1
  48:   84 91        lpm r24, Z
  4a:   08 95        ret
```

It should be noted that, not only has the linker moved the pieces around
to their final addresses, it has also fixed the arguments of the `ldi`
instructions so that they now point to the correct address of my_array.

Comment: To confirm, the array is read-only and each member is a byte in length. Ideally I would like to avoid coding in C first, because although simpler to implement, I struggle to learn by reverse engineering the disassembled code due to the differences you stated. 

Referring to your first code snippet where you explain how to declare the array. Where in that segment is the specification for the base address in the array?

Furthermore is it possible to declare members, addresses and offsets in hexadecimal? I assume the use of decimal and hexadecimal values are interchangeable for these values.

Comment: @Daniel Dunn: You do not specify the base address of the array, you let the linker put it where it sees fit. You _do_ associate a symbol (`my_array`) and use the same symbol when accessing the array. The linker will then take care of matching the symbol usage with its definition. And yes, you can write numbers in hex if you want.

Comment: If the base address is specified for you, could you give an example of  how you would access or refer to the value 34 in my_array.

Comment: @DanielDunn: I already provided the example: it's the implementation of `read_data` in the second code snippet. The important thing to notice is that `my_array` is referred to _by name_ in the `ldi` instructions. The assembler will generate an `ldi register, 0` instruction, irrespective of the actual address of the array. The linker will fix this later. C.f. “_The role of the linker_” in my expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look something like this:

```
    .section    .text
    .global main
main:
    ldi r30,lo8(data)
    ldi r31,hi8(data)
    ldd r24,Z+3
    sts output,r24
    ld r24,Z
    sts output,r24
    ldi r24,0
    ldi r25,0
    ret
    .global data
    .data
data:
    .byte   1, 2, 3, 4
    .comm   output,1,1
```

### Explanation

For people who have programmed in assembler using the GNU toolchain before, there are lessons that are transferable even to unfamiliar instruction sets:

1. You reserve space for an array with the assembler directives `.byte 1, 2, 3, 4`, `.word 1, 2` (`.word` is 16 bits for AVR) or `.space 100`.
2. When learning a new instruction set, write C programs and ask the C compiler to generate assembler output. Find a good assembler programming reference for the instruction set as you read the assembler code.

Applying this trick below.

### byte-array.c

```
/* volatile our code doesn't get optimized out even when compiler optimization is on */
volatile char output;

char data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main(void)
{
    output = data[3];
    output = data[0];
    return 0;
}
```

### Generate Assembler from C

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega8 -Wall -Os -S byte-array.c
```

This will generate the assembler file `byte-array.s`.

### byte-array.s

```
    .file   "byte-array.c"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
/* prologue: function */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    ldi r30,lo8(data)
    ldi r31,hi8(data)
    ldd r24,Z+3
    sts output,r24
    ld r24,Z
    sts output,r24
    ldi r24,0
    ldi r25,0
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
.global data
    .data
    .type   data, @object
    .size   data, 4
data:
    .byte   1
    .byte   2
    .byte   3
    .byte   4
    .comm   output,1,1
    .ident  "GCC: (Fedora 4.9.2-1.fc21) 4.9.2"
.global __do_copy_data
.global __do_clear_bss
```

Read this [explanation of Pointer Registers](http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/REGISTER.html#Pointer-register) to see how the AVR instruction set uses the `r30`, `r31` register pair as the pointer register `Z`. Read up on the `ld`, `st`, `ldi`, `ldd`, `sts` and `std` instructions.

### Implementation Notes

If you link the program then disassemble it:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega8 -Os byte-array.c -o byte-array.elf
avr-objdump -d byte-array.elf

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   12 c0           rjmp    .+36        ; 0x26 <__ctors_end>
   2:   2c c0           rjmp    .+88        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   4:   2b c0           rjmp    .+86        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   6:   2a c0           rjmp    .+84        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   29 c0           rjmp    .+82        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   a:   28 c0           rjmp    .+80        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   27 c0           rjmp    .+78        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
   e:   26 c0           rjmp    .+76        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   25 c0           rjmp    .+74        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  12:   24 c0           rjmp    .+72        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   23 c0           rjmp    .+70        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  16:   22 c0           rjmp    .+68        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   21 c0           rjmp    .+66        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  1a:   20 c0           rjmp    .+64        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:   1f c0           rjmp    .+62        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  1e:   1e c0           rjmp    .+60        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  20:   1d c0           rjmp    .+58        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  22:   1c c0           rjmp    .+56        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>
  24:   1b c0           rjmp    .+54        ; 0x5c <__bad_interrupt>

00000026 <__ctors_end>:
  26:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  28:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  2a:   cf e5           ldi r28, 0x5F   ; 95
  2c:   d4 e0           ldi r29, 0x04   ; 4
  2e:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  30:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61

00000032 <__do_copy_data>:
  32:   10 e0           ldi r17, 0x00   ; 0
  34:   a0 e6           ldi r26, 0x60   ; 96
  36:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  38:   e4 e8           ldi r30, 0x84   ; 132
  3a:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
  3c:   02 c0           rjmp    .+4         ; 0x42 <__SREG__+0x3>
  3e:   05 90           lpm r0, Z+
  40:   0d 92           st  X+, r0
  42:   ac 36           cpi r26, 0x6C   ; 108
  44:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  46:   d9 f7           brne    .-10        ; 0x3e <__SP_H__>

00000048 <__do_clear_bss>:
  48:   10 e0           ldi r17, 0x00   ; 0
  4a:   ac e6           ldi r26, 0x6C   ; 108
  4c:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  4e:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2         ; 0x52 <.do_clear_bss_start>

00000050 <.do_clear_bss_loop>:
  50:   1d 92           st  X+, r1

00000052 <.do_clear_bss_start>:
  52:   ad 36           cpi r26, 0x6D   ; 109
  54:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  56:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x50 <.do_clear_bss_loop>
  58:   02 d0           rcall   .+4         ; 0x5e <main>
  5a:   12 c0           rjmp    .+36        ; 0x80 <_exit>

0000005c <__bad_interrupt>:
  5c:   d1 cf           rjmp    .-94        ; 0x0 <__vectors>

0000005e <main>: ...

00000080 <_exit>:
  80:   f8 94           cli

00000082 <__stop_program>:
  82:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0x82 <__stop_program>
```

You can see `avr-gcc` automatically generates *startup code*, including:

- the interrupt vector (`__vectors`), which uses `rjmp` to jump to the Interrupt Service Routines.
- initialize the status register, `SREG` , and the stack pointer, `SPL/SPH` (`__ctors_end`)
- copies the data segment content from FLASH to RAM for initialized, writable global variables (`__do_copy_data`)
- clears the BSS segment for uninitialized writable global variables (`__do_clear_bss` etc)
- calls our `main()` function
- calls `_exit()` if `main()` ever returns
- `_exit()` is just a `cli` to disable interrupts
- and an infinite loop (`__stop_program`)

Comment: The startup code is actually from avr-libc. `__do_copy_data` and `__do_clear_bss` are from libgcc, and are linked into the program only if needed.